# Understanding algorithm language syntax

Tags: algorithm

https://codility.com/media/train/3-PrefixSums.pdf

I am trying my hand at algorithms on codility. I am stuck at one of the notations used in the algorithm in the above link.

What does P = [0] * (n + 1) mean? Which language is this?

Thanks
R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other terms, such as `xrange`, shows the language is Python. Generally, search the web for the words you see in code, as it may help to know what is the name of the language.

In Python, `[0]` is a list containing a single zero, and `[0] * (n + 1)` is a list of `(n + 1)` zeroes, like `[0, 0, ..., 0]`.

Comment: Thanks, Gassa. I realized after posting the question that it was Python. So, basically the code above is just initializing a list with zeros, is it?

Comment: @rishi: right. Then all zeroes except the first one are overwritten, so the positive impact is just setting the length and the first element.

Comment: Thanks! I cannot mark this as an answer as I don't have enough reputation points.

Comment: @rishi: You should be able to mark a post as the answer no matter how much reputation you have: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-posts.  Maybe you were looking at the upvote arrow instead?  That takes 15 reputation.